# When trying to create an image label inside of labelimg it boots me out to the cmd

Tags: python, labelimg

I have been trying to continue my datasets for my yolov5 model today. But when I am inside labelimg and try to create a box around the target, the application closes and I left with this error message:

[image]

It has been working perfectly fine for the last 2 weeks, adding images and creating text files has not been a problem, until now.

I have even tried to create a new open and change directory location in labelimg to test it but I get the same outcome.

Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: Please provide error messages as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Edit your post to remove any images of text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  classes.txt file with your labels to  your folder.